# Unexpected Token '%' observed while running nodeJS application and express(pino)

Tags: node.js, express, logging

I am unable to identify the rootcause for the error shown below.The error is observed frequently while running node server. Once I restart the node server the application runs normally without any issues.

**1. I would like to know what makes this error appear**

**2. Is there anything to do from the developers end with which the issue can be resolved**

**Error:**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token %
    at EventEmitter.Pino (/code/node_modules/pino/pino.js:144:19)
    at EventEmitter.child (/code/node_modules/pino/pino.js:284:10)
    at loggingMiddleware (/code/node_modules/pino-http/logger.js:45:32)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /code/node_modules/express-boom/index.js:28:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/code/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at query (/code/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at EventEmitter.handle (/code/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:174:10)
    at Server.app (/code/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:39:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
```

Comment: This has to do with the native runtime function `%FlattenString` and not using `--allow-natives-syntax` – see https://github.com/davidmarkclements/flatstr/commit/689e327f8ad82f4d9c017185fb064f791beecf0a#diff-168726dbe96b3ce427e7fedce31bb0bc